# Child metas Profile pages are Oops

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, per-site-meta, network-profile, 500-server-error

I've tried a half dozen child metas, the main site's **Profile** pages are fine but the child meta Profiles are oops. The child meta site's pages (not my profile) work fine.

Examples:

- Oops - [https://medicalsciences.**meta**.stackexchange.com/users/current](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- OK - https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/current
- Oops - [https://skeptics.**meta**.stackexchange.com/users/current](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- OK - https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/current
- Oops - [https://philosophy.**meta**.stackexchange.com/users/current](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- OK - https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/current

Tried logging out and back in. It has been occurring for over 20 minutes.

**Error Message:**

> **Oops! Something Bad Happened!**
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: is it still an issue for you, Rob? I can access those just fine now. Caching?

Comment: @AntonMenshov Thanks for your assistance. The bug has been confirmed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We had one server going a bit crazy with memory (from a competing process) - I've gotten a dump, cycled the issue (to restore production), and will dig into what's causing it first thing tomorrow. Thanks for the report!

Comment: That kick has fixed it, on a half dozen meta Profiles that I've tested. Only thing is to find out what caused it in the first place. Thanks for the speedy reply and repair.

Comment: If this has been diagnosed to determine why it happened could this be marked status completed, I've had no problems accessing any pages since.